# jQuery para Javascript Puro (usar export function ES6)

Tags: javascript

Esse script transforma a primeira letra de cada palavra em maiúsculas, exceto algumas palavras que fazem parte das matrizes nas variáveis `wordContainAt, wordsToIgnore, wordUpperCase`.

Estou tendo problemas para refatorar o código criado no `jQuery` para `JavaScript Puro`. Pretendo utilizar `módulos de exportação ES6`.

Eu sei que a exportação não tem nada haver com a função, mas neste contexto, acho que não entendi muito bem o conceito de uma `função anônima`, ou `arrow function`, porque não consego obter o objeto `this`dentro do escopo da função, como acontece em jQuery.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

**jQuery**

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $.fn.capitalize = function() {
        // words to ignore
        let wordContainAt = '@',
            wordsToIgnore = ['to', 'and', 'the', 'it', 'or', 'that', 'this'],
            wordUpperCase = ['S.A', 'SMS', 'USA'],
            minLength = 2;

        function getWords(str) {
            if (str == undefined) {
                str = 'abc def';
            } else {
                str = str;
            }
            return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
        }
        this.each(function() {
            let words = getWords(this.value);
            console.log(words);
            $.each(words, function(i, word) {
                // only continues if the word is not in the ignore list or contains at '@'
                if (word.indexOf(wordContainAt) != -1) {
                    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
                } else if (wordUpperCase.indexOf($.trim(word).toUpperCase()) != -1) {
                    words[i] = words[i].toUpperCase();
                } else if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word)) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
                }
            });
            if (this.value != '') {
                this.value = words.join('');
            }
        });
    };

    // field onblur with class .lower
    $(document).on('blur', '.lower', function() {
        $(this).capitalize();
    }).capitalize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="lower" />
```

**Exemplo Javascript**

```
const capitalizeTheWord = () => {
    constole.log(this) // undefined

    const inputWordCapitalize = document.querySelector('input.lower');
    inputWordCapitalize.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
        // capitalizeTheWord...
    });
};

export default capitalizeTheWord();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de tudo, vale deixar claro que no JavaScript, uma função anônima não é, necessariamente, uma *arrow function*. Funções anônimas são simplesmente aquelas que não recebem nome.

Veja, primeiramente, um exemplo de uma função nomeada:

```js
function doStuff() { /* ... */ }
//       ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
//    Nome da função
```

E alguns exemplos de funções anônimas:

```
const doStuff1 = function() {};

const doStuff2 = () => {};
```

Note que a função em si não possui nome. Como retornam uma expressão, serão atribuidas às variáveis `doStuff1` e `doStuff2`, que irá *armazenar* a função — anônima. Note que você ainda poderá invocá-las normalmente, já que são funções.

Funções anônimas são geralmente usadas como *callbacks*. Se você irá criar uma função que você mesmo irá chamar, é sempre preferível declará-la usando um nome.

---

Agora no contexto de *arrow functions*, vale, em primeiro lugar, consultar a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Em resumo, o `this` está `undefined` porque toda *arrow function* não cria um valor `this` para o seu próprio escopo. O `this` é herdado do escopo pai.

Desse modo, como o escopo pai da sua *arrow function* é o próprio módulo, `this` será `undefined`.

Veja um exemplo que ilustra o comportamento da *arrow function* de não criar um valor `this` para seu próprio escopo, herdando o escopo do pai:

```js
class Class {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
  
  doStuff() {
    console.log(this.foo);
    
    // Note que estamos retornando uma arrow function:
    return () => {
      console.log(this.foo);
    };
  }
}

const instance = new Class('Given String');
const returnedFn = instance.doStuff(); // Irá imprimir no console: "Given String"
returnedFn(); // Irá imprimir no console: "Given String"
```

A título de comparação, veja o mesmo exemplo, mas alterando a *arrow function* por uma função anônima convencional:

```js
class Class {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
  
  doStuff() {
    console.log(this.foo);
    
    // Note que estamos retornando uma função anônima convencional:
    return function() {
      console.log(this); // `this` é undefined. Se tentar acessar `foo`, um erro será lançado.
    };
  }
}

const instance = new Class('Given String');
const returnedFn = instance.doStuff(); // Irá imprimir no console: "Given String"
returnedFn(); // Irá imprimir no console: undefined
```

---

Visto isso, eu não sei nem porque você quer acessar o `this` dentro da função que você já está chamando ao exportá-la. Aliás, você não está nem exportando a função, mas sim o seu retorno, que me parece vir a ser `undefined`, porque não há `return` explícito.

#### Para saber mais:

- [*Arrow Functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions);
- [*Callable values*](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_callables.html#kinds-of-functions), capítulo 23 do excelente livro *JavaScript for impatient programmers*.